# How to read List object in JSP using OGNL tags

Tags: struts2, ognl

My requirement is to read Objects of `List` from `Session` in `JSP` using `OGNL`.

In my action class,

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setName("xyz");

Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setName("123");


ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(emp1);
list.add(emp2);

session.setAttribute("listObj", list);
```

So am trying to check name in Jsp
pseudo code ::

```
`IF TEST ="#session.list.get(0).getName()"=="xyz"
print :: xyz user.
ElSE
   print :: guest user..`
```

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo code is here.

```
IF TEST ="#session.list.get(0).getName()"=="xyz"
print :: xyz user.
ElSE
print :: guest user..
```

The `listObj` is actually session-scoped attribute. So you access it in two ways:

1. `#session.objectname` or
2. `#session['objectname']`

You can use `equals()` method for comparing `string`s.

```
   <s:if test="%{#session.listObj.get(0).getName().equals("xyz")}">
       <h2>xyz user</h2> 
   </s:if>
   <s:else>
       <h2>guest user</h2>          
   </s:else>
```